# How can I match something if it doesn't contain specific word?

Tags: php, regex

Here is my string:

```
$str = "this is a string
        this is a test string";
```

I want to match everything between `this` and `string` words *(plus themselves)*.

**Note:** between those two words can be everything except the word of `test`.

So I'm trying to match `this is a string`, but not `this is a test string`. Because second one contains the word of `test`.

---

Here is my current pattern:

```
/this[^test]+string/gm
```

[But it doesn't work as expected](https://regex101.com/r/ENHYLD/2)

How can I fix it?

Comment: i didn't get the `test` part. can you please explain

Comment: @mrid I want to match every sentence which starts with `this` and ends with `string` if that sentence doesn't contain the word of `test`.

Comment: @mrid Vice versa of this https://regex101.com/r/ENHYLD/3

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it treats the "test" as a list. Thus looking for something that contains none of the characters.

Comment: salam @Shafizadeh ! soale khoobi bood eyval !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you did it it was excluding any characters in the list "test". The way to do this would be using `negative lookarounds`. The regex would then look like this.

`this((?!test).)*string`

Comment: You need to make it `lazy` by adding `?`, to be like this `this((?!test).)*?string`. test your regex to the following `this is a string this is a string this is a string this is a string this is a string`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do this without regex, you can use [`fnmatch()`](http://php.net/fnmatch)

```
function match($str)
{
    if (strpos($str, 'test') == false) /* doesn't contain test */
    {
        if (fnmatch('this*string', $str))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```